# How do I map a java.util.List[Array[String]] to a Scala vector?

Tags: scala, data-structures

**Background**

I have a `java.util.List[Array[String]]` called `rawdata` coming directly from opencsv's `CSVReader`

```
val reader = new CSVReader( new FileReader( "foobar.csv" ))
val rawdata = reader.readAll();
```

Currently, I'm looping through `rawdata` and grabbing `rawdata.get(i)(4)` and `rawdata.get(i)(5)` for fields 4 and 5 in record `i` where i goes from 0 to 99,999.

**Problem**

Instead, I would like to map `rawdata` into a `Vector[Record]` where the constructor for `Record` takes fields 4 and 5 from above.  There are 100,000 records in `rawdata`.

This is where I hit a bit of cognitive dissonance because `Vector` is immutable, but `java.util.List[Array[String]]` requires that I loop through it (there is no `map` for me to call, AFAIK)...

**Question**

*How do I map the `java.util.List[Array[String]]` to `Vector[Record]`*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scala provides a set of conversions from Java collections, which you can use like this:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val records = rawdata.asScala.toVector.map(toRecord)
```

Where `toRecord` is some method like the following:

```
def toMethod(fields: Array[String]) = Record(fields(4), fields(5))
```

You could also perform the mapping operation with a function literal:

```
val records = rawdata.asScala.toVector.map { fields =>
  Record(fields(4), fields(5))
}
```

Both of these versions will convert the `java.util.List` to a `scala.collection.mutable.Buffer`, then to a `Vector`, and then perform the mapping operation. You could save one intermediate collection like this:

```
val records: Vector[Record] = rawdata.asScala.map(toRecord)(collection.breakOut)
```

Or you could convert to an iterator on the Java side:

```
val records = rawdata.iterator.asScala.map(toRecord).toVector
```

The simplest version's probably best, though, unless you're sure this is a bottleneck in your program.

Comment: ty - this is almost there - how do I plug in a functor so I can map fields 4 and 5 to Record's constructor?

Comment: tyvm - works great - I really learned a lot about Scala with this answer - much appreciated.